# Could somebody explain the error in my trigger?

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER ATUALIZAR_EMPRESTIMO AFTER INSERT ON EMPRESTIMO FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE EXEMPLAR EX SET STATUS = 'EP' FROM EMPRESTIMO E, EMPRESTIMO_EXEMPLAR EE
            WHERE EE.CDEMPRESTIMO = NEW.CDEMPRESTIMO AND EE.CDEXEMPLAR = EX.CDEXEMPLAR;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This is an English speaking website. You would need to translate your question to English, or maybe go ask it on [Stackoverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Also, it would be good if you could share the error message that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but you will eventually have to limit the results of your select or at least concat the result or so

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ATUALIZAR_EMPRESTIMO AFTER INSERT ON EMPRESTIMO FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE EXEMPLAR EX SET STATUS = (SELECT 'EP' FROM EMPRESTIMO E, EMPRESTIMO_EXEMPLAR EE
        WHERE EE.CDEMPRESTIMO = NEW.CDEMPRESTIMO AND EE.CDEXEMPLAR = EX.CDEXEMPLAR);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```